# Ruby on rails + jquery - how to use

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am just learing and i've  come across a problem. I'd like burger icon to work, but it doesn't work. ----> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/album/# It doesn't collapse.

I add

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

to gemfile and then type `bundle update` it installed jquery

Fetching jquery-rails 4.4.0
Installing jquery-rails 4.4.0

then i added

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

to the application.html.erb and the script below

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/docs/4.5/assets/js/vendor/jquery.slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script><script src="/docs/4.5/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

from bootstrap example website and it doesn't work, what do I do wrong?

/ application.html.erb

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>AlbumSite</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/album/">

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css' %>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>




<style>

.jumbotron {
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .jumbotron {
    padding-top: 6rem;
    padding-bottom: 6rem;
  }
}

.jumbotron p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.jumbotron h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  max-width: 40rem;
}

footer {
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
}

footer p {
  margin-bottom: .25rem;
}

      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="collapse bg-dark" id="navbarHeader">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-7 py-4">
              <h4 class="text-white">About</h4>
              <p class="text-muted">Add some information about the album below, the author, or any other background context. Make it a few sentences long so folks can pick up some informative tidbits. Then, link them off to some social networking sites or contact information.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 offset-md-1 py-4">
              <h4 class="text-white">Contact</h4>
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Follow on Twitter</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Like on Facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Email me</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark shadow-sm">
        <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">
          <a href="<%= home_path %>" class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" aria-hidden="true" class="mr-2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" focusable="false"><path d="M23 19a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V8a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4l2-3h6l2 3h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2z"/><circle cx="12" cy="13" r="4"/></svg>
            <strong>Album</strong>
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarHeader" aria-controls="navbarHeader" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <main role="main">

  <section class="jumbotron text-center">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Simple album</h1>
      <p class="lead text-muted">Something short and leading about the collection below—its contents, the creator, etc. Make it short and sweet, but not too short so folks don’t simply skip over it entirely.</p>
      <p>
        <a href="<%= new_post_path %>" class="btn btn-primary my-2">Add a new album</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>

    <%= yield %>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/docs/4.5/assets/js/vendor/jquery.slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script><script src="/docs/4.5/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

/ javascripts' folder -> application.js

```js
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, or any plugin's
// vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: If you inspect that page are there any errors in red?  If you view the page source do you see all the js files being included?

Comment: https://iv.pl/image/rubyjq.Gt2UHx2 there is a photo* what i got in my folder tree and i opened application.js file

Comment: There are no errors tho.

Comment: Don't link to images, you can just edit the question to inlcude that.  So no errors when you inspect the page, did you view the source to verify that the js files are being included on the page?

Comment: I haven't got 10+ reputations points to post an image :D There is the script with the source files. I didn't find anything else.

Comment: No just put the code in there, don't link to images in the question either